# Unable to disconnect VPN dial-up connection started by another Windows user

Tags: windows-7, vpn, multiple-users, dial-up

On Windows 7 Pro, I have a VPN dial-up connection, I start it manually as needed (connects to VPN server over the home DSL) while logged in as UserA.

However, when I switch to my other Windows account as UserB (without logging off), forgetting to disconnect the VPN, I try to disconnect it, but I get a message saying "`It is not possible to disconnect at this time. The connection is currently busy with a connect or disconnect operation.`", but of course, it is not. The connection is active, working, and stable. It just cannot be disconnected, unless I log in again as UserA and disconnect it from there.

Is there a way to be able to establish the VPN connection by one user and be able to disable it by the other?

Both users are local Administrators...

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, there's no option in Windows where you can disconnect another user from VPN. The only thing O found is this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/remoteaccess/disconnect-vpnuser.

Comment: What I understand from the provided link is that the cmdlet runs on the server, right? I'm not experienced with powershell, but it appears to be not exactly what I am looking for.